# grep the word if matching with condition

Tags: linux, shell

I have 2 words "static**ed2f**.css" and static**ec3f**.css . The bold char do change offen. I want to grep these words matching 'static'  using grep command or any other script

Thank you

Comment: Those 2 words are in 2 different files , i always have to find out those words so we can say the versions have changed

Comment: Are these words always ending with `.css`? Provide few more examples.

Comment: Few words with .js and few with .css

Comment: You can use: `static[^.]*\.(css|js)` regex but better to show examples in question.

Comment: file1 >> galleryed2f.js
gas.mined2f.js
jquery.easing.1.3ed2f.js
jquery.elastislideed2f.js
jquery.tmpl.mined2f.js
pngfix.mined2f.js
script.calculatorsed2f.js
script.customed2f.js
script.custom.js
script.formed2f.js
script.mined2f.js
sorttableed2f.js

Comment: file 2 >> jquery-1.7.1.mined2f.js
bootstrap.mined2f.js
jquery.validateed2f.js
jquery.cycle.mined2f.js
jquery.selectBox.mined2f.js
jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.mined2f.js
jquery.multiselect.mined2f.js
jquery.ezmark.mined2f.js
script.heightfixed2f.js
autoresizeed2f.js
jquery.royalslider.mined2f.js
script.customed2f.js
script.mined2f.js

Comment: The above are the two files

Comment: Oh not in comment, you need to edit the question and provide it there,  otherwise no one can understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
grep -o \static[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.css
```

To change with other word,

```
var="otherword"
grep -o \(static\|$var)[\-a-zA-Z0-9.]*\.(css|js)
```

Comment: How to do that using a variable- The static word might change to other word